# How to set text content of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I set the `textContent` of `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` on their respective elements by a loop?

```
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
const li3 = document.createElement('li');
const a1 = document.createElement('a');
const a2 = document.createElement('a');
const a3 = document.createElement('a');

ul.append(li1,li2,li3);
li1.appendChild(a1);
li2.appendChild(a2);
li3.appendChild(a3);

a1.textContent = 'About';
a2.textContent = 'Menu';
a3.textContent = 'Contact';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the content to an array and iterate over it using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as follows:

```js
const sections = document.getElementById("sections");
const ul = document.createElement('ul');

const data = ['About', 'Menu', 'Contact'];

data.forEach(section => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.textContent = section;
  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.append(li);
});

sections.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="sections"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the text of each element in an array, so you can then create the elements in a loop.

```js
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
const texts = ['About', 'Menu', 'Contact'];
for(const text of texts){
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.textContent = text;
  li.append(a);
  ul.append(li);
}
document.body.append(ul);
```